# Can we run terraform import in Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have already created Azure virtual networks and resource groups manually. I am going to create a VM using Terraform and deploy it via Azure DevOps.My Terraform state file resides in an Azure Storage account. Currently, it is blank. I need to import the existing virtual network and resource groups into the state file. I am able to do the Terraform initialize, plan and apply using the release pipelines but I am not able to find a task in the release pipeline to import terraform. I can import using my VSCode, but I need to do this import using Azure DevOps.

Could someone let me know if that is possible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Azure Pipelines extension claims to support Terraform import: [Terraform Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charleszipp.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform&targetId=f2a914ae-4030-4b32-acf2-667db357d03a)

Answer (score 2):

> Can we run terraform import in Azure DevOps release pipeline

I am afraid there is no such out of box task to run terraform import in Azure DevOps release pipeline at this moment.

There is user voice about it on Developer Community:

[Support for Terraform Import](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/640596/support-for-terraform-import.html)

> It would be great if we are creating infrastructure via the Azure Portal to then be able to **bring those resources into Terraform state management via a simple Terraform import** task rather than attempting to call this in a PowerShell/Bash/Azure CLI script.
> Currently the Terraform task supports plan, init, apply etc. But not import

You could vote and add your comments for this feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Terrafy is a different way to solve this problem.  You would run this against existing infrastructure, and it would generate Terraform for you and add it to a state file.

https://github.com/Azure/aztfy

It does have some limitations, which are discussed here:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/azure-terrafy-import-your-existing-azure-infrastructure-into/ba-p/3357653

Answer (score 0):

You could... or you could setup your local terraform to read your state in AZ and then, import locally, saved to AZ and you're done.

Something along the lines of:

```
terrafrom init 
  -backend-config=storage_account_name=<storageaccountname> 
  -backend-config=container_name=<container_name> 
  -backend-config="key=statefile.terraform-state" 
  -backend-config=resource_group_name=<rg-name> 
  -backend-config=subscription_id=<subid> 
  -backend-config=tenant_id=<tenantid>
```

As so:

```
terrafrom init 
  -backend-config=storage_account_name=terraform_state 
  -backend-config=container_name=dev 
  -backend-config="key=dev-app-uk.terraform-state" 
  -backend-config=resource_group_name=terraform-state 
  -backend-config=subscription_id=0000-0000-0000-0000 
  -backend-config=tenant_id=9999-9999-9999-9999
```

Then import your resources as so, and it will save right up to AZ all imported

Comment: Your answers will be easier to understand if you take a little time to format them properly.  :-)